# Меняется шрифт при выходе из админ панели Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

При выходе из админ панели вордпресса шрифт меняется на другой. Вот [ссылка](http://skidkus.kz) Интересно что меняется только русский а английский остаётся. Поставил все основные шрифты Open Sans. вот CSS

```css
body,

button,

input,

select,

textarea {

 color: #092f40;

 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;

 font-size: 14px;

 font-size: 1.4rem;

 line-height: 18px;

}



/* Headings */

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {

 clear: both;

 margin-bottom: 10px;

}

h1{

 font-size: 36px;

 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;

 font-weight: 400;

 }

h2{

 font-size: 24px;

 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;

 font-weight: 400;

 }

h3{

 font-size: 18px;

 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;

 font-weight: 400;

 }

h4{

 font-size: 16px;

 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;

 font-weight: 400;

 }

h5{

 font-size: 14px;

 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;

 font-weight: 400;

 }

h6 {

 font-size: 12px;

 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;

 font-weight: 400;

 }

hr {

 background-color: #ccc;

 border: 0;

 height: 1px;

 margin-bottom: 1.5em;

}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратил внимание на то, что Вы как-то странно подключаете шрифт, лучше это делать по-другому.

Подключаем в `head`-е:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

В css -

```
.class { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; }
```

Если шрифт меняется на `Helvetica`, то нужно поменять его в `bootstrap.css` на тот, что нужно.

Так же, если Вы хотите везде использовать "свой" шрифт, то имеет смысл писать так `* {font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}`

Comment: Благодарю. Вопрос решен.